# What is the max number of characters are allowed in a Phone field?

Tags: api, soap-api, data-types

What is the maximum number of characters allowed in a field set with the Phone type? The [online documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/field_types.htm#i1435705) that I found only says:

> Phone fields contain phone numbers, which can include alphabetic characters. Client applications are responsible for phone number formatting.

But I do not see any mention of the max size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on a [different page](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_fields.htm&language=en_US):

> *Phone*: Primary phone number of account. Up to 40 characters are allowed in this field.

So the answer seems to be **40 characters**.